# Unable to display MapView in LiteMode inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-maps-android-api-2, android-mapview

I have a list of saved locations coming from the server that I want to display inside a RecyclerView with a map snapshot of the location.
I coded it according to code samples provided for the same by Google but unfortunately the list wouldn't show on the UI.
I am attaching the code to my RecyclerView Adapter & item XML.

```
public class SavedLocationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SavedLocationAdapter.ViewHolder>  {
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<SavedLocationDetails> savedLocationList;
private LoadMoreLocationsInterface loadMoreLocationsInterface;

public SavedLocationAdapter(Context context, LoadMoreLocationsInterface loadMoreLocationsInterface) {
    //super(DIFF_CALLBACK);
    super();
    mContext = context;
    this.savedLocationList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.loadMoreLocationsInterface = loadMoreLocationsInterface;
}

public void updateList(List<SavedLocationDetails> savedLocationList) {
    this.savedLocationList.addAll(savedLocationList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_saved_location, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    SavedLocationDetails savedLocationDetails = savedLocationList.get(position);
    if (savedLocationDetails != null)
        holder.bindView(savedLocationDetails);
    if (position == getItemCount()-1)
        loadMoreLocationsInterface.loadMoreLocations(savedLocationDetails.getLid());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return savedLocationList.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    MapView mapView;
    TextView locationType;
    TextView friendlyName;
    TextView fullAddress;
    public GoogleMap map;
    View layout;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        layout = itemView;
        locationType = layout.findViewById(R.id.savedLocationTypeTV);
        fullAddress = layout.findViewById(R.id.savedLocationAddressTV);
        friendlyName = layout.findViewById(R.id.friendlyNameTV);
        mapView = layout.findViewById(R.id.savedLocationMap);
        if(mapView != null) {
            mapView.onCreate(null);
            mapView.onResume();
            mapView.onPause();
            mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(mContext);
        map = googleMap;
        setMapLocation();

    }

    private void setMapLocation() {
        if (map == null)
            return;
        SavedLocationDetails savedLocationDetails = (SavedLocationDetails) mapView.getTag();
        if (savedLocationDetails == null)
            return;
        LatLng locationLatLng = new LatLng(savedLocationDetails.getLat(), savedLocationDetails.getLng());
        BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location_marker_black_solid);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = (new MarkerOptions()).position(locationLatLng).icon(icon);
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(locationLatLng, 18f));
        map.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

    public void bindView(SavedLocationDetails savedLocationDetails) {
        layout.setTag(this);
        mapView.setTag(savedLocationDetails);
        setMapLocation();
        if((savedLocationDetails.getLtp() != null) && (savedLocationDetails.getLtp() == 3)) {
            locationType.setVisibility(GONE);
            friendlyName.setText(savedLocationDetails.getFn());
            friendlyName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            friendlyName.setVisibility(GONE);
            locationType.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            locationType.setText("Home");
        }
        fullAddress.setText(savedLocationDetails.getAdd());
    }
}

}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/appBar"
    app:cardElevation="3dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="30dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/savedLocationMap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="225dp"
            app:mapType="normal"
            map:liteMode="true"
            map:mapType = "normal" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/savedLocationDataRL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/savedLocationMap"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:visibility="gone">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/savedLocationTypeTV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Work"
                android:textColor="@color/quantum_black_100"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/friendlyNameTV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Friendly Name"
                android:textColor="@color/quantum_black_100"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/savedLocationAddressTV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/savedLocationTypeTV"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:text="Full Address"
                android:textColor="@color/quantum_black_100"
                android:textSize="13sp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Hey I was facing same issue but I made it works, did you find a solution for this or should I post an answer? if you still need an answer, can you share the XML?

Comment: @MiguelHincapieC It was working from the very start.. Just that I didn't enable my recycler view..